# How to change 3d coordinate system?

Tags: geometry, 3d, coordinate-systems

I want to change coordinate system from $(x,y,z)$ to $(x_n,y_n,z_n)$ (Figure is attached). What I mean is that I want to assign new $x,y,z$ axes.

What I know about new lines $(x_n,y_n,z_n)$:

1. origin is at $(x=k,y=0,z=k^2)$, where $k\geq1,$
2. $z_n$ line is parallel to $y$ line and passes through new origin $(x=k,y=0,z=k^2)$,
3. $y_n$ line is equal to line $z=(k+k^{-1})x-1$ where $y=0$,
4. $x_n$ line is equal to line $z=-\frac{1}{k+k^{-1}}x+\frac{k^4+2k^2}{k^2+1}$ where $y=0.$

[image]

How to perform such transformation and how to read points on old coordinate, for example (3,2,-1), on new coordinate system?

Comment: First off, clearly the new z-coordinate of any point is just the old y-coordinate, and the rest can be done in a plane (the old xz-plane, the new xy-plane). So that takes the problem down one dimension. Should make it a little easier to keep things straight.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_of_axes

Comment: Have you noted that the slopes $s$ and $s'$ of lines $y_n$ and $x_n$ are such that $ss'=-1$, therefore are orthogonal.

Comment: @JeanMarie yes, I have calculated the second line equation based on the fact that they are orthogonal